# Validetta Server-side validation with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do ASP.NET MVC server-side validation using Validetta.
I'm trying to figure out the signature of my action that provides me access to the form data.

In 'Validetta' site, they've provided a demo but using PHP, and, I apologize but, I'm clueless in PHP. So how would it translate into an MVC method. http://lab.hasanaydogdu.com/validetta/demo/remote.html (Server side tab)

Comment: did you do any research yourself into how validation is done in MVC? There are lots of examples, tutorials etc out there which explain the structures you can use... TBH in MVC you might not even need this 3rd-party plugin for client-side validation, since you can have MVC generate the client-side and server-side validation code automatically based on the attributes you give to each property in your Model class. Even if you have more complex validation requirements you can add custom methods to it using a defined process.

Comment: Of course, I'm talking about 'Validetta' remote validation and not just any validation

Comment: True.. But this is not my decision. I'm working on a large project that already uses 'Validetta'

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/Asp-Net-mvc-server-side-validation/ would get you started. When validation fails you can return the model state errors as JSON.

Comment: You mean like returning `JsonResult` from the controller's method,  and using anonymous object to contain the appropriate result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a method to be used for Validetta server-side validation, I used the below:

```
    public ActionResult ValidateAddress()
    {
        var address = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["Address"];
        var isValid = CheckAddress(address);

        return Json(new
        {
            valid = isValid,
            message = !isValid ? "Please enter a valid address" : string.Empty
        });
    }
```

using the below Validetta initialization:

```
$("form.validetta").validetta({
    errorClass: 'v-error',
    realTime: true,
    validators: {
        remote: {
            check_address: {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'url/Controller/ValidateAddress',
                datatype: 'json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```